# How do I extract an ECM archive in Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, applications, archive

I came across a ECM archive that I need to extract.
The Unarchiver can't handle this format, and I'm not sure about other utilities.

How do I extract ECM in Mac OS X Lion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the ECM tools created by Neill Corlett, the creator of ECM. Just run "unecm" on the file.

[There are binaries for Mac here](http://www.neillcorlett.com/cmdpack/)

If that seems intimidating, there is a [youtube walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=ipPKp2X8efM) here that uses a GUI and contains links to the tools used.

Comment: Hey dan did you get this to work? i just bought a mac and it's lion as well. but when i follow that youtube video and try to open the GUI it gives me the error that powerpc isnt supported anymore. help anyone?

Comment: +1 for command line tools. The video is down though

Comment: Note that ecm is also available via HomeBrew.

Comment: The binary link is broken, but Homebrew still works good! (thanks @TimVisher)

Comment: To update for 2015:
```brew install ecm; ecm *.ecm;```
and you're good to go!